# Python ast package: traversing object hierarchies

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, myhdl

The following is a Python code snippet using the *ast* and *symtable*
packages.  I am trying to parse the code and check the types.  But I 
don't understand how to traverse **objects** to get to the actual variable 
being referenced.

The following code implements a NodeVisitor, and a function is presented to the compiler and parsed by the compiler and the ast walked.  The function being analyzed (eval_types) is passed a couple objects.

Below are the code chunks that make up the example.  I have added some comments for each chunk.  To run the code, the "chunks" need to be reassembled.

The imports and a function to un-indent a block of code for parsing.

```
import inspect
import ast
import symtable
from tokenize import generate_tokens, untokenize, INDENT
from cStringIO import StringIO

# _dedent borrowed from the myhdl package (www.myhdl.org)
def _dedent(s):
    """Dedent python code string."""

    result = [t[:2] for t in generate_tokens(StringIO(s).readline)]
    # set initial indent to 0 if any
    if result[0][0] == INDENT:
        result[0] = (INDENT, '')
    return untokenize(result)
```

The following is the node visitor, it has the generic unhandled and name visitor overloads.

```
class NodeVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, SymbolTable):
        self.symtable = SymbolTable
        for child in SymbolTable.get_children():
            self.symtable = child
            print(child.get_symbols())

    def _visit_children(self, node):
        """Determine if the node has children and visit"""
        for _, value in ast.iter_fields(node):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    if isinstance(item, ast.AST):
                        print('  visit item %s' % (type(item).__name__))
                        self.visit(item)

            elif isinstance(value, ast.AST):
                print('  visit value %s' % (type(value).__name__))
                self.visit(value)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        print(type(node).__name__)
        self._visit_children(node)

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        print('  variable %s type %s' % (node.id,
                                         self.symtable.lookup(node.id)))
        print(dir(self.symtable.lookup(node.id)))
```

The following are some simple classes that will be used in the function that will be parsed and analyzed with the AST.

```
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = None

class MyObjFloat(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1.

class MyObjInt(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class MyObjObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.xi = MyObjInt()
        self.xf = MyObjFloat()
```

The following is the test function, the eval_types function is the function that will be analyzed with the AST.

```
def testFunc(x,y,xo,z):

    def eval_types():
        z.val = x + y + xo.xi.x + xo.xf.x

    return eval_types
```

The code to execute the example, compile the function and analyze.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    z = MyObj()
    print(z.val)
    f = testFunc(1, 2, MyObjObj(), z)
    f()
    print(z.val)
    s = inspect.getsource(f)
    s = _dedent(s)
    print(type(s))
    print(s)

    SymbolTable = symtable.symtable(s,'string','exec')
    tree = ast.parse(s)
    v = NodeVisitor(SymbolTable)
    v.visit(tree)
```

The following is an example output up to the first name visit.

```
Module
  visit item FunctionDef
FunctionDef
  visit value arguments
arguments
  visit item Assign
Assign
  visit item Attribute
Attribute
  visit value Name
  variable z type <symbol 'z'>
['_Symbol__flags', '_Symbol__name', '_Symbol__namespaces', 
 '_Symbol__scope', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', 
 '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', 
 '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
 '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
 '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'get_name', 'get_namespace', 
 'get_namespaces', 'is_assigned', 'is_declared_global', 
 'is_free', 'is_global', 'is_imported', 'is_local', 
 'is_namespace', 'is_parameter', 'is_referenced']
```

Creating the node visitor doesn't seem to bad but I can't figure out
how to traverse an object hierarchy.  In the general case the variable 
being accessed could be buried deep in a object.  How to get to the actual variable being accessed from the ast visitor?  I only see that an *object* is at the node but no additional information what the result variable access is.

Comment: not sure i follow what you want.  is it that you can't find ".val"?  have you tried recursing below that node?  it's a long time since i used this, but i seem to remember that you would need, in your case, to call visit_children from visit_name.

Comment: @andrewcooke Thanks for the comments!  Yes, I want to continue parsing the objects (z.val, xo.xi.x, xo.xf.x) and determine more information on the actual variable used in the statement.  The simple case would be, z = x + y + xo_xi_x + xo_xf_x, where the variables are not embedded (buried) in objects and the properties/attributes/type of the variable could be determined in the above code snippet.  I will experiment with calling visit_children explicitly on these types of nodes.  Thanks again.

Comment: Making small (slow) progress developing an understanding of the AST package.  For this example, the object "attributes" will travel down the **visit_Attribute**.  Now I simply need to determine when **visit_Name** has an object (has children?) then finish in the visit_Attribute and work backwards (back up the tree).

Comment: good luck.  the docs are terrible/non-existent - you just need to read all the source you can... (but it's pretty cool code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for this, but it looks like you just need to add a `visit_Attribute` and traverse backwards.  If you add this to your example:

```
def visit_Attribute(self, node):
    print('  attribute %s' % node.attr)
    self._visit_children(node)
```

Then the output for `xo.xf.x` is:

```
Add
  visit value Attribute
  attribute x
  visit value Attribute
  attribute xf
  visit value Name
  variable xo type <symbol 'xo'>
  visit value Load
```

Depending what you want to do with this, you would just need to store the attributes in a list until a `Name` is encountered, then reverse them.